# How to create subclass from abstract class ui,Image in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to get an local asset image loaded into an ui.Image object. But the ui.Image is an abstract class. I basically have this :

```
    import 'dart:ui' as ui;
    class MyImage implements ui.Image{

    int height;
    int width;

    MyImage(String file){

    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return super.toString();
     }
    }
```

Using your code with the function definition Below. The error is at 
' ui.Image image = await loadImage(img); ' await is underlined red and tool tip is 'Undefined name 'await' in function body not marked with async.'

```
    class TrialApp extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _TrialAppState createState() => new _TrialAppState();
    }

    class _TrialAppState extends State<TrialApp> {

        NodeWithSize rootNode;

    @override
    void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        rootNode = new NodeWithSize(new Size(400.0, 400.0));
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // define a function that converts the I.Image object into ui.Image 
    //object
        Future<ui.Image> loadImage(I.Image img) async {
        final Completer<ui.Image> imageCompleter = new Completer();
        ui.decodeImageFromList(img.getBytes(), (ui.Image img) {
          imageCompleter.complete(img);
        });

        return imageCompleter.future;
        }

    // Obtain a `I.Image` object from the image file
    I.Image img = I.decodeImage(new io.File('images/tile.png').readAsBytesSync());

    // Obtain the `ui.Image` from the `I.Image` object
    ui.Image image = await loadImage(img);

   Sprite myButton = new Sprite.fromImage(image);
   rootNode.addChild(myButton);
   return new SpriteWidget(rootNode);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Why would you want it? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: I'm was trying to get an 'images/image.png' from assets into an Image object from the dart:ui. To use as a parameter in a function from an external package called 'Spritewidget'. Sprite.fromImage(ui.Image image) Checking the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SpriteWidget you can load images using the `ImageMap` class to save some code. From the SpriteWidget docuementation:

```
ImageMap images = new ImageMap(rootBundle);

// Load a single image
ui.Image image = await images.loadImage('assets/my_image.png');

// Load multiple images
await images.load(<String>[
  'assets/image_0.png',
  'assets/image_1.png',
  'assets/image_2.png',
]);

// Access a loaded image from the ImageMap
image = images['assets/image_0.png'];
```

Answer (score 1):

First obtain the image from the assetbundle using [`rootBundle`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/rootBundle.html). The convert the obtained `ByteData` to `List<int>`. Now you can obtain a `ui.Image` using the `decodeImageFromList` method.

Example:

```
// import statements
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:spritewidget/spritewidget.dart';

class TrialApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TrialAppState createState() => new _TrialAppState();
}

class _TrialAppState extends State<TrialApp> {
  NodeWithSize rootNode = new NodeWithSize(new Size(400.0, 400.0));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future<Null> init() async {
    rootNode = new NodeWithSize(new Size(400.0, 400.0));

    // Read file from assetbundle
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('images/tile.png');

    // Convert the obtained ByteData into ui.Image
    final ui.Image image = await loadImage(new Uint8List.view(data.buffer)); // Uint8List converts the ByteData into List<int>

    Sprite myButton = new Sprite.fromImage(image);
    rootNode.addChild(myButton);

    // notify to redraw with child
    setState(() {
      rootNode = rootNode;
    });
  }

  // define a function that converts the List<int> into ui.Image object
  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(List<int> img) async {
    final Completer<ui.Image> imageCompleter = new Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
      imageCompleter.complete(img);
    });

    return imageCompleter.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new SpriteWidget(rootNode),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry missed async keyword after `loadImage`. Edited answer

Comment: I've updated my answer to include async keyword, hope you saw it. You can edit your question to include code. Or You can create a gist on git and share your link to the code.

Comment: I've added the code to my question with the error. Could it be that because ui.Image is an abstract class? b'cos documentation says it cannot be instantiated. I'm new to coding.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to achieve the same for your usecase without `image` package.

Comment: Phew !! Oh Yes! It works. Thank you very much. And should some of the previous comments be deleted, it clutters the place.